# Refresh ListView item with Image's Source bound to property

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have problem with refreshing my listview data. It doesn't update unless I call:

```
List.ItemsSource = null;
List.ItemsSource = listviewSource;
```

This is works but doesn't look good (screen flashes) so I wanted to use, as people suggested, INotifyPropertyChanged.

My listviewSource is ObservableCollection< Class2> where Class2 implements Class1 and Class1 implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    ...
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{

    private string ImgSource;

    public string imgSource
    {
        get { return this.ImgSource; }
        set
        {
            this.ImgSource = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("imgSource");
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

imgSource is binded to ListView but when it changes nothing happens... Am I doing something wrong?

XAML markup

```
<ListView x:Name="List" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Loaded="List_Loaded">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Tag="{Binding number}" Background="#FF0E1D23" Margin="0,5" >
                        <Image Margin="339,10,23,13" Source="{Binding imgSource}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: To be honest I am not sure whether `Source` binding works in such a way with `Image`. You may try to change it Binding [Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.mode) to `OneWay` (perhaps it is `OneTime` by default). P.S.: Also, just to be sure that I correctly understand the problem - you change `imgSource` but the appropriate image does not change? Or you change the collection(add, remove `Class2` from the `ObservableCollection`) but there are no changes in the listView?

Comment: i change ImgSource but the image stays the same - but when i call the source to be null and then set again - then the image changes

Comment: ok i got it working :D thans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Image`'s `Source` default [binding mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.mode) is `OneTime`.

Change it explicitly to `OneWay`:

```
Source="{Binding imgSource, Mode = OneWay}"
```

Comment: but still even with INotifyPropertyChanged there is a little flash of screen , smaller but still is :)

Comment: @JakubWisniewski Unfortunately, that is how image change works with binding. Perhaps you can create changed invisible image at the same place as the old one(just beneath) and then remove the old. But it will require a fair bit of UI code and, I think, will be problematic to achieve with some layouts. Perhaps there are some guidelines over the net that deal with this mildly embarrassing effect. Also, you may try to tinker the size of the image (bigger image will obviously cause longer lag).